# form action attribute not working in html

Tags: html

Below code not working.
When i click submit its not submit value.

```
<form action="404/index.php?s_id=200" method="post" name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
    <div class="row">

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email *" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
            </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <div id="success"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl" onClick="404/index.php?s_id=200">SUBSCRIBE NOW</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It isn't submitting what value?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: The `onclick` attribute takes the body of a JavaScript function as its value. Your URL isn't valid JavaScript so will just throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need onClick on  to get working form. Also action should have URI to script without additional parameters (?s_id=200). If you want to stay on the same page after form is submited you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: Why action attribute shouldn't have additional parameters?

Comment: "You don't need onClick on to get working form." — True, but irrelevant. "Also action should have URI to script without additional parameters" — **false** if it was a GET form (which it isn't) then the query string would be discarded. "If you want to stay on the same page" — **false** you could also use a No Content response from the server, but also irrelevant since nobody mentioned staying on the same page before you.

Comment: It's not irrelevant, especially when it's not valid. It's clearly POST form, so there shouldn't be any additional parameters. Last part was just additional info, because he will ask this later.

Comment: @DejanMarolt — Exactly, so the query string won't be destroyed, so having one there is fine.

Comment: There is no rule that forbids making a POST request to a URL with a query string.